# Save a "click to edit" with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm making a simple list application and the items should be easy to edit (just clicking on them). It works fine, but I still have a problem at saving the changes to the database, for some reason it doesn't happen. I'm sure it's a code problem, but I haven't been able to find it.

**List Page**

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden" id="hidden" value="">
<ul id="lista">
<?php
    $IDllista = 1;
    $selectitems = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM items WHERE IDllista=".$IDllista." ORDER BY posicio ASC") or die (mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($selectitems))
    {
        echo'<li class="item"  id="';
        echo $row['IDitem'];     
        echo     '"><span class="edit" id="span-';
        echo $row['IDitem'];
        echo '" data="';
        echo $row['Text'];
        echo '">';
        echo $row['Text'];
        echo'</span></li>';
    }
?>  
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
//Call the edit function

$(".edit").live("click", function () {
    // Get the id name
    var iditem = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    var element = this;
    var id = element.id;

    //New text box with id and name according to position
    var textboxs = '<input type="text" name="text' + id + '" id="text' + id + '" class="textbox" >'
    //Place textbox in page to enter value 
    $('#'+id).html('').html(textboxs);
    //Set value of hidden field
    $('#hidden').val(id);
    //Focus the newly created textbox
    $('#text'+id).focus();
});

// Even to save the data - When user clicks out side of textbox
$('.edit').focusout(function () {
    //Get the value of hidden field (Currently editing field)
    var field = $('#hidden').val();
    //get the value on text box (New value entred by user)
    var value = $('#text'+field).val();
    //Update if the value in not empty
    if(value != '') {
        //Post to a php file - To update at backend
        //Set the data attribue with new value
        $(this).html(value).attr('data', value);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id: iditem}, 
            url: 'editartext.php'
        });
    }

    // If user exits without making any changes
    $(".edit").each(function () {
        //set the default value
        $(this).text($(this).attr('data'));
    }); 

});
```

**Edit Page**

```
<?php
    include_once "../connect.php";
    $IDitem = $_POST['id'];
    $noutext = "hola";
    $actualitza = mysql_query ("UPDATE items SET Text = ".$noutext." WHERE IDitem = ".$IDitem." ");
?>
```

Comment: `$noutext` is a string so it should be quoted, if `$IDitem` is a string it should be quoted too, it should also be sanitized.

Comment: `jQuery.live()` has been deprecated as of version 1.7 and removed in 1.9.  You may still be on an old version but it would be ideal to update and use currently supported portions of the API

Comment: I can't tell for sure what's wrong with your code but you should print something in the server side to check 'id' and to check the result of the query.

Comment: It's good practice to use something like MySQLi or PDO instead of mysql_query/connect. http://codular.com/php-mysqli

Answer (score 0):

Quote problem i think. You can use query with single quote like;

```
"mysql_query("UPDATE items SET Text ='$noutext' WHERE IDitem ='$IDitem'");
```